# My item is not shown in the TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**Problem**: After I add a "todo" and click on "Save", the new todo is not listed in the TodoTableView .

full code: https://github.com/gkatsanos/todolist-swift

I am following the apple [make your first app guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH16-SW1) but using XCode 8 (Swift 3) - so I suspect some of the code has changed.

Specifically this part:

```
@IBAction func unwindToMealList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? MealViewController, meal = sourceViewController.meal {
        // Add a new meal.
        let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: meals.count, inSection: 0)
        meals.append(meal)
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
    }
}
```

which I corrected to:

```
@IBAction func unwindToTodoList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let source = sender.source as? TodoViewController, let todo = source.todo {
        // Add a new todo.
        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: todos.count, section: 0)
        todos.append(todo)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation .bottom)
    }
}
```

(I am slightly changing the example to do "Todos" instead of meals.)

I am running my up, and putting a breakpoint to that method, the if never evaluates to true so my new todo is not saved.

I used a breakpoint and I inspect the variables and see that the text I input is somewhere in sender.source (@TEST) [image]

This is the Todo.swift base class:

```
class Todo {
    // MARK: Properties

    var name: String

    // MARK: Initialization

    init?(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        if (name.isEmpty || name == "") {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of source? If `UIViewController`, you forgot to set the controller class in your storyboard.

Comment: @LeoNatan : to set it where?

Comment: In your storyboard, select the source controller and in the inspector in IB (right side), set the class to `TodoViewController`.

Comment: I am afraid that was already the case. :( (I assume source controller is the one where you actually add the new item)

Comment: OK, then the problem is in your `todo` property. It returns nil. If your text comes from a text field, you need to override the getter of the property to return the textfield's text.

Comment: @LeoNatan : I added the rest of the code through a github url in the question https://github.com/gkatsanos/todolist-swift

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125725/discussion-between-george-katsanos-and-leo-natan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the actual code suggested by the guide, doing the following:

```
// This method lets you configure a view controller before it's presented.
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let name = nameTextField.text ?? ""

        // Set the todo to be passed to TodoTableViewController after the unwind segue.
        todo = Todo(name: name)
}
```

For the `override` to work I had to change sender to be of type `Any` instead of `AnyObject` and I removed the conditional.

It's the closest I could get to the code provided by the [Apple Start Developing iOS Apps guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH16-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `todo` is empty. You have a text field, but you attempt to get you text from the property. Change this property to a computed property, and in the getter, return the text of the text field.

Change it like so:

```
var todo?: Todo {
    get {
        return Todo(name: nameTextField.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: check my method tableView(.. ), isn't that enough? Could you maybe add a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

As @Leo pointed, your `todo` is empty when you `unwind` your `viewController`. You have one action method in your `TodoViewController` where you can assign value to your `todo`. Try this:

```
    @IBAction func AddTodo(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if let name = nameTextField.text , !name.isEmpty {
            todo = Todo(name: name)
            saveButton.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

Another option as you have `unwind`, you could get your `textField's value in this method and add your`todo` item.

```
@IBAction func unwindToTodoList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? TodoViewController {
        if let name = sourceViewController.nameTextField.text {
            sourceViewController.todo = Todo(name: name)
            let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: todos.count, section: 0)
            if let todo = sourceViewController.todo {
                todos.append(todo)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.bottom)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do this just above,     `// MARK: Navigation
    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if saveButton === sender {
            let name = nameTextField.text ?? ""
            
            // Set the todo to be passed to TodoTableViewController after the unwind segue.
            todo = Todo(name: name)
        }
    }`

Comment: Who is calling your `prepare`? How are you using it

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson8.html there, towards the bottom of the document (or cmd+f prepareFor )

Comment: That I know, but check your segues. Score using this method. You have to configure /add the segues properly.

Comment: OK so the prepare method is _not_ called... but I have no idea why

Comment: Because you are not performing a segue, you are unwinding. This is different.

Comment: Try the other option, let me know if that helps